# Spring batch repository logging

Tags: spring, spring-batch

Can the sql calls made by spring batch to store job repository information be logged? i am using oracle database and i am unable to find a way to log those calls.

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?83802-View-the-SQL-generated-by-Spring-Batch) link on the Spring forums may help.

The Spring Batch framework will just use the Spring Framework JDBC classes so adjusting the core logging will give you what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your requirement, it would be better to use hibernate as your ORM for spring batch because, it has the capability to log sql statements. Below is an example, that I created using hibernate.

```
https://github.com/alex-fernandez/create-batch-job-mysql
```